# OAuth 2.0 authorization for TeamViewer in C# and its getting sessions list

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, teamviewer

I want to receive a list of open sessions in Team Viewer via a C# program. I read the [Team Viewer API documentation](https://dl.tvcdn.de/integrate/TeamViewer_API_Documentation.pdf).

As per the documentation, OAuth 2.0 authentication is used to get an access token. But I am not able to understand, how do I pass credential information to it. Just for testing, I also tried to create an access token using [Postman Rest API](https://www.getpostman.com/) but I am not able to do that as well.

```
string Version = "v1";
string tvApiUrl = "https://webapi.teamviewer.com/";
string address = tvApiUrl + "/api/" + Version + "/sessions";
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

//SOMEHOW I HAVE TO ASSIGN CREDENTIAL/AUTHENTICATION TO REQUEST HERE

request.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an authorization code first [(3.8.1)](https://dl.tvcdn.de/integrate/TeamViewer_API_Documentation.pdf#page=14), and then, using that code, request an access token (3.8.2).

You will then use the access token in the authorization header in all the other requests.